# Add animation when changing tabs

Tags: android

Hello
I have a TabHost activity with two child activities. What would be the best solution to add a "left - right" animation for the child activities?

Best regards!

Answer (score 9):

Hi
The best solution for this is to add animation to layouts
suppose you have two tabs

```
tabs = (TabHost) this.findViewById(R.id.tabhost_id);
        tabs.setup();    
        tspec1 = tabs.newTabSpec(name_of_1st_tab)
        tspec1.setIndicator(....);
        tspec1.setContent(R.id.tab_1_layout_id);
  tab1Layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.tab_1_layout_id);

   tspec2 = tabs.newTabSpec(name_of_2nd_tab)
        tspec2.setIndicator(....);
        tspec2.setContent(R.id.tab_1_layout_id);
  tab1Layout = (LinearLayout)findViewByIdR.id.tab_2_layout_id);
```

then on the TabChangedListener

```
    tabs.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
  tab1Layout.setAnimation(outToLeftAnimation());
  tab2Layout.setAnimation(inFromRightAnimation());
             }
      });

   public Animation inFromRightAnimation() {

    Animation inFromRight = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, +1.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
    inFromRight.setDuration(ConstandsUsed.ANIMATIION_DURATION);
    inFromRight.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    return inFromRight;
}

public Animation outToLeftAnimation() {
    Animation outtoLeft = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, -1.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f);
    outtoLeft.setDuration(ConstandsUsed.ANIMATIION_DURATION);
    outtoLeft.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    return outtoLeft;
}
```

Hope this will help you to get some idea

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The thing is that I have an activities tab host, not a views tab host.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you. The main idea is to get the current view for the tab and set animation for it in onTabChanged event.

```
tabsHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

    public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
        View currentView = tabsHost.getCurrentView();
        currentView.setAnimation(<Your animation object goes here>);
    }
});
```