# How to animate tab change with support library Actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-support-library

I use ActionbarSherlock that uses a support Actionbar for API level prior 11. I found [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077440/add-animation-when-changing-tabs) to animate 'normal' tab change but I don't know how I could reference *tab views* from the Actionbar. Is there a good way to animate ActionBar of tab change?

Comment: you want to animate tabs in actionbar?

Comment: Yes. I have a few tabs and when a user touches them, a listview is refreshed. I want to start an animation of 'moving tabs' like the link in my post.

Answer (score 1):

The Link you posted is an old solution for your goal. Actually using TabHost for implementing tabs is deprecated. You have to use Actionbar tabs with viewpager. There's a built in animation in viewPager. There are several tutorial for implementing actionbar tabs with viewPager. My recommendation is to use support library not actionbar sherlock but here is a great tutorial.

http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-actionbarsherlock-viewpager-tabs-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Call the animation functions setAnimation(outToLeftAnimation()); and setAnimation(inFromRight());
inside the onTabSelected() function, as per the tab position. Thank you. Hope it will help you.